# Is it possible to get the last restore date of a MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql, restore

*Is it possible to get the last restore date of a MySQL database?*

I am going to restore the database from a `.sql` dump file, but I don't know how to get from the database, the last time when a restore happened.

I tried to query the `information_schema.tables` table in order to check the `creation_time` of each table, but they seem to be not updated after the restore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested your solution about the "CREATE_TIME" field in information_schema and I think it's the good one, look :

```
[root@localhost] [MFO] mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = "myisammfo"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
   TABLE_SCHEMA: MFO
     TABLE_NAME: myisammfo
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: MyISAM
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Fixed
     TABLE_ROWS: 2
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 7
    DATA_LENGTH: 14
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 1970324836974591
   INDEX_LENGTH: 1024
      DATA_FREE: 0
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2013-03-05 15:15:22
    UPDATE_TIME: 2013-03-05 15:17:58
     CHECK_TIME: 2013-03-05 15:18:28
TABLE_COLLATION: latin1_swedish_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS:
  TABLE_COMMENT:
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I did a mysqldump of MFO DB:

```
predator:~# mysqldump -uroot -p --databases MFO >/tmp/MFO.SQL
```

Then loaded it:

```
predator:~# mysql -uroot -p </tmp/MFO.SQL
```

Now the CREATE_TIME is today:

```
predator:~# mysql -uroot -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 86261
Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5 (Debian)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

[root@localhost] [(none)] mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = "myisammfo"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
   TABLE_SCHEMA: MFO
     TABLE_NAME: myisammfo
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: MyISAM
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Fixed
     TABLE_ROWS: 2
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 7
    DATA_LENGTH: 14
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 1970324836974591
   INDEX_LENGTH: 1024
      DATA_FREE: 0
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2013-10-02 16:45:56
    UPDATE_TIME: 2013-10-02 16:45:56
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: latin1_swedish_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS:
  TABLE_COMMENT:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Best regards.

Max.

Comment: Hi mfouilleul, thank you for your reply! Actually I am using an InnoDB engine and the above mentioned approach did not work.

Comment: Hi, what version of MySQL do you have. I have no difference between MyISAM or InnoDB with this approach.

Comment: Hi, I'm using mysql community server 5.5.25. I tried the solution you pasted above, but when I restore the data the create_time does not change.

Comment: Hi mfouilleul, the problem has been solved using the solution you provided here. The `create_time` is actually changed after the restore, I was checking a table belonging to a different schema. Thank you!

Comment: SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = "oneofyourtables" ORDER BY Create_TIME DESC; -- list create_time for each database with above table (very useful thanks)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux you can also make a **ls -l** on your datadir to show the creation date of your schemas folder :

```
[root@db-prod-03 ~]# ls -l /database/data/mysql | grep test
drwxrwx--- 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jul 30 12:59 test
```

Best Regards.

Max.

Answer (score 0):

In your **mysqldump**, did you put the **mysql** schema in it?

The **mysql** schema contains the **information_schema** datas so when the mysql is restored, the past infos are loaded... understand?

Max.

Comment: Edit : I did three answers because it's three differents approaches.

Comment: I used the same syntax you provide in the previous answer (e.g.: mysqldump -uroot -p --databases MFO > /tmp/MFO.SQL), but the date does not change. 
Anyhow, each time I query the information_schema tables their creation_time change (also without performing a dump). Instead, the creation_time of my own schema does not.

Comment: Also, the `.sql` produced by my dump does not contain any operation on the information_schema

Comment: information_schema does not contains tables, it contains views. The datas are stored in mysql schema.